# C++ regex: Which group matched?

Tags: c++, regex

I have a regex containig various sub-groups which are connected through an or condition:

```
([[:alpha:]]+)|([[:digit:]]+)
```

When I match the string `1 a 2`, I get three matches: `1`, `a` and `2`.

Is there a way in C++ to determine which of the sub-patterns matched?

Comment: Create a minimal running example. Mention which regex library you're using. The answer right now is yes, no more details can be given.

Comment: Why do you need to know which group is matched?

Comment: If you're using `std::regex` you can pass a `match_results<...>` object when you do the match. That will hold an array of `sub_match<...>` objects, and you can iterate through that array to find the one(s) that matched.

Answer (score 3):

Not directly.

with the `std::regex` library, **match_result** class takes care of the **sub-match** and it has a method named [std::match_results::size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/size) and with that you can find the number of sub-match.

Ex:

```
std::string str( "one two three four five" );
std::regex rx( "(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)(\\w+)" );
std::match_results< std::string::const_iterator > mr;

std::regex_search( str, mr, rx );

std::cout << mr.size() << '\n'; // 6
```

here the output is **6** not **5** because the match itself is counted as well. You can access them by `.str( number )` method or `operator[]`

So because sub-match are counted form **left-to-right** you should after seeing the output of **size** method figure out witch group was matched.

If you change the **rx** to `"(\\w+)(\\d+)(\\w+)"` then the size = 0

If you change the **rx** to `"(\\w+).+"` then the size is **2**. That means you have a **whole successful match** and a **sum-match**

Ex:

```
std::string str( "one two three four five" );
std::regex rx( "(\\w+).+" );
std::match_results< std::string::const_iterator > mr;

std::regex_search( str, mr, rx );

std::cout << mr.str( 1 ) << '\n'; // one
std::cout << mr[ 1 ] << '\n';     // one
```

the output for both is: **one**

And also if you want to print only the **sub-match** you can use a simple loop that has an **index** and this index starts from **1** not **0**

Ex:

```
std::string str( "one two three four five" );
std::regex rx( "(\\w+) \\w+ (\\w+) \\w+ (\\w+)" );
std::match_results< std::string::const_iterator > mr;

std::regex_search( str, mr, rx );

for( std::size_t index = 1; index < mr.size(); ++index ){
    std::cout << mr[ index ] << '\n';
}
```

the output is:

```
one
three
five
```

---

By saying *determine which of the sub-patterns matched*
if you mean specify which **sub-match** should be return from the **search-engine** then the answer is **yes** by using `std::regex_token_iterator` you can determine that:

Ex: (Iterate over **second** sub-match of each match )

```
std::string str( "How are you today ? I am fine . How about you ?" );
std::regex rx( "(\\w+) (\\w+) ?" );
std::match_results< std::string::const_iterator > mr;

std::regex_token_iterator< std::string::const_iterator > first( str.begin(), str.end(), rx, 2 ), last;

while( first != last ){
    std::cout << first->str() << '\n';
    ++first;
}
```

the **last parameter is 2** : `( str.begin(), str.end(), rx, 2 )` and it means you want only the **second sub-match**. So the output is:

```
are
today
am
about
```